# A question about measurable sets and positive and negative function part.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ a measureble function. We define $f_+:=\max\{f,0\}$ and $f_-:=\max\{-f,0\}.$

Can I say that $$\{f=+\infty\}=\{f_+=+\infty\},$$ and $$\{f=-\infty\}=\{f_-=+\infty\}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you mean by $\{ f = a \}$ is $\{ x \in X : f(x) = a \}$. If so, then yes, this is correct.